# Google Maps API 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps')' when loading component using onMount() in Vue3

Tags: vue.js, google-maps-api-3, vuejs3, google-maps-api-2, vue-composition-api

I'm creating a Vue app and using Google Maps API to render a map but when I try loading it, I receive the error 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps')'

I don't know where this error is coming from as I've imported the google map Loader function using:

I'm assuming it's coming from the google object maps property here:

```
onMounted(async () => {
            await loader.load()
            new google.maps.Map(mapDiv.value, {
                center: currPos.value,
                zoom: 14
            })
        })
```

I've taken a screenshot of the error
[Error from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz9yy.png)

I've imported the Loader from google maps in the component itself, and also in the view that renders the component.

```
import { Loader } from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader'
```

However, on page load it still throws the error that maps is not found.
'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps')'

The Loader comes from an npm package here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader

Answer (score 0):

`google` variable is not defined in your script, which should be a response, so assign the response from `load` method to `google` variable :

```js
onMounted(async () => {
           let google =  await loader.load()
             new google.maps.Map(mapDiv.value, {
                center: currPos.value,
                zoom: 14
            })
        })
```